# Smoothing overlapping stroke edges

Tags: svg, raphael

I'm using Raphael to draw the arcs as shown in the image below:
[image: SVG used to draw 3 arcs]

Z-index order is from lowest to highest: gray, blue, green.
Both the gray and the blue arcs start from the top, where the green one starts.

Is there any way to improve the edges? Especially the green over blue one.

Thank you.

Comment: (assuming this is not reproducing in webkit driven browsers) have you tried applying [`renderfix()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.renderfix)?

Comment: Thanks, Eliran, the screenshot is from Chrome Canary unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there's not much you can do. How the shape is rendered depends on the viewer (browser, image viewer or importing application). You could play with the [rendering properties](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#RenderingProperties) and see if this gives you an improvement, but I believe hardly any SVG implementation supports them.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure exactly what you mean, and it is hard to know how you made the image without the raphael code. Are you talking about the way the outer edge of the green arc extends slightly beyond the outer edge of the blue arc? I would check that the corner points of the two paths are the same, and include the stroke-width in your calculations of the paths.

Perhaps you could try reducing the stroke-width to 0 to make things easier.

Comment: Hello, all 3 are `A` ellipsis arcs. They are independent of each other, just overlapped. Setting the stroke to 0 would hide them entirely, there is no fill.

Comment: And yes, I mostly mean the green-over-blue edge, but other edges as well. Not sure if I should be looking for anti-aliasing properties or if there's anything else that can be done.

Comment: oh, i get it now, i think. you tried changing the stroke-linecap to butt? beyond that im not sure. Thomas is probably right that it is down to the specific rendering of the browser

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are overlapping the shapes. This causes some colors to spill out from underneath. To solve this you need to start each arc where the previous one ends.

You might get very faint gaps, this can easily solved by applying a 1px stroke to each arc.

Comment: Thank you, but what you are seeing are strokes.